# Creating popularity bars in css/html

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a popularity bar like that of Spotify

[image]

Anyone know of any good tutorials (havn't been able to find any). Or have any code builds of their own?

Comment: is this about the graphics only? you do not want to use images? SVGs? please give more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a pure HTML and CSS solution. You could also do this with SVG.

http://codepen.io/tylerism/pen/xGpQwQ

HTML

```
<div class="pop_line active">

</div>
<div class="pop_line active">

</div>
<div class="pop_line active">

</div>
<div class="pop_line">

</div>
<div class="pop_line">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.pop_line{
  background:#444;
  border-radius:3px;
  width:5px;
  height:20px;
  float:left;
  margin:2px;
}
.pop_line.active{
  background:#999;

}
html{
  background:#111;
}
```